# Need to just get the number value from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that I am getting from a Jquery selector .html that is
**example**

```
<span class="currency">$</span>"&nbsp;477,000.00"
```

I want to just get the 477000.00 value so that I can use this as a number for some calculations.

I tried a parseInt and it returns Nan.

Here is my code for selecting:

Here is my actual code:

```
function getSystemPrice() {
    var currentSystemPrice = $("#bom-div-content table tbody tr td").html();
    currentSystemPrice = parseInt(currentSystemPrice);
    $("#SYSTEM_PRICE_TILES_ONLY").val(currentSystemPrice);
}
```

Comment: Show us your current code.

Comment: The `span` is closed before the number is output, that's why you don't get a value. Besides, you will need to remove the $ anyways, otherwise `NaN` is the result of parsing.

Comment: What are the possible formats of numbers.

Comment: I am just trying to get a number the number value since this would be in different currency's.

Comment: Don't pull the html....get the text ...then string would be `$ 477,000.00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```js
var string = '<span class="currency">$</span>"&nbsp;477,000.00"';
var output = parseFloat(string.match(/([\d,.]+\.)/)[1].replace(/,/g, ''));
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

**UPDATE**:

```js
var string = '<span class="currency">$</span>"&nbsp;477,000.00"';
var string2 = '<span class="currency">$</span>"&nbsp;12.477.000,00"';
var re = /((?:\d{1,3}[,.]?)+)[,.](\d{2})/;
var m = string.match(re);
var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML += parseFloat(m[1].replace(/[,.]/g, '') + '.' + m[2]) + '\n';
m = string2.match(re);
output.innerHTML += parseFloat(m[1].replace(/[,.]/g, '') + '.' + m[2]);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Regex explanation:

- `(
  (?:         non capturing group
    \d{1,3}   1 to 3 digits
    [,.]?     optional comma or dot
  )+          at least one of those
  )` the whole is wrap in parenthesis so it capture the whole thing (number before last comma or dot)
- `[,.]` the last comma or dot (not captured)
- `(\d{2})` capturing group that match last 2 digits

Comment: This will match `.,1,.2,.4.,`

Comment: @Tushar I've assumed it have valid number in html.

Comment: Would this code work if it was in Euros where it would be something like: 477.000,00

Comment: Okay, you don't need capturing group. use `.match(/[\d.,]+/)[0]`

Comment: @jcubic that worked great! If I my number was 477,000.12 would this code work also or is it just rounding to a whole number.

Comment: @jcubic I am new to the match function can you explain to me what this all did. /((?:\d{3}[,.]?)+)[,.](\d{2})/

Comment: @DennisCafiero Added regex explanation.

Comment: @jcubic I just noticed that the code does not work if it is 4,770,000.00 or higher.

Comment: @DennisCafiero I've updated the regex it's now /((?:\d{1,3}[,.]?)+)[,.](\d{2})/

Answer (score 0):

What are the possible values you get? If you always get "$" "  you can split the string on the ; str.split(";"). If you know the number is always the last part of the string, you must pick of the characters from the end (using e.g. str.slice(-1) and stop when you get characters that does not make sense as a number.

Comment: The number will always be at the end like it is. The only thing that might change is the , and . because of the way the displaying of currency is treated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function getSystemPrice() {
    var currentSystemPrice = $("#bom-div-content table tbody tr td").html();
        currentSystemPrice = currentSystemPrice.replace("$","");  //Here you take out the $
        currentSystemPrice = currentSystemPrice.replace(" ","");  //Here you take out white spaces
        currentSystemPrice = parseFloat(currentSystemPrice);  //This way you will have decs if its needed
    $("#SYSTEM_PRICE_TILES_ONLY").val(currentSystemPrice);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your code would work by using the replace but as written it does not work for the code but I could replace certain parts of the string with "" and get to my number using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to parse the number as an int or a float, as there's two ways to do this.

To parse as an int, you should pass a second argument to parseInt, the radix (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
parseInt("10", 10);
```

This is because most implementations use 10 as a default radix, but NOT all, so it might be a subtle source of bugs later down the line.

Taking the jQuery out of it and simply reading the number in as a string and converting it to a float, I did like this:

```
var tmp = "<span class='currency'>$</span>&nbsp;477,000.00".split("&nbsp;")[1];
parseFloat(tmp.split(",").reduce((a, b) => a + b ));
```

You could of course use parseInt instead of parseFloat as explained earlier, depending on the exact nature of the data you want.

Not sure if it's the solution you are looking for but I thought I'd see if I could get it done using reduce, I don't mind admitting I learned something here too.